# Sorting a Range object in VSTO

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

In VSTO 2010 in Excel, the `Range.Sort` method doesn't seem to work for me. Here's my example code. It puts the numbers 1 to 20 in reverse order in column A, and then unsuccessfully tries to sort them.

```
Worksheet sheet = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet;
Enumerable.Range(1, 20).ToList().ForEach(i => sheet.Cells[21 - i, 1] = i);
sheet.Columns[1].Sort();
```

According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.sort.aspx), the `Sort` with no arguments will sort in ascending order. Just in case I tried specifying `Order1: XlSortOrder.xlAscending`.

I also tried

`sheet.Columns[1].Select().Sort();`

to select the column first, but this didn't work either.

How can I sort a `Range` of cells?

Comment: What happens when you run the sample code?

Comment: @phoog It puts the numbers 1 to 20 in reverse order in Column A of the active worksheet. But it doesn't sort them in ascending order.

Comment: What does it do instead of sorting them in ascending order?  Do you get an exception like the VBA error I indicated in my answer?

Comment: @phoog Yes, I was missing the exception at first, but I also got it like you did. Adding the Key1 argument fixed my code as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your approach in VBA and receved the error "sort method of range class failed".

I resolved that by passing the range as the "Key1" argument of the method.  Seems redundant, but it works.  Here's your sample code with the same fix applied:

```
Worksheet sheet = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet;
Enumerable.Range(1, 20).ToList().ForEach(i => sheet.Cells[21 - i, 1] = i);
sheet.Columns[1].Sort(sheet.Columns[1]);
```